# How do I find least square between two matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, feature-extraction, sift, hessian-matrix

What is the replacement in MATLAB for the following line of code snippet in python?
From  [Python Implementation for SIFT Feature Extraction](https://github.com/rmislam/PythonSIFT)

```
 x = -lstsq(hessian, gradient, rcond=None)[0]
```

> if
>
> hessian = [-0.001 -9.042 -9.491;-9.042 -2.345 -7.983;-9.491 -7.983
> -7.269] and gradient = [1.6 6.1 9.3]

The following is what is implemented currently in MATLAB but gives a localization error for SIFT Feature Extraction

```
[U,S,V] = svd(hessian); %singular value decomposition for eigenvectors 
T=S;
T(S~=0) = 1./S(S~=0);  
invH = V .* T' .* U'; %inverse hessian
x = - invH.*gradient;
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
x = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]
```

is the solution to the linear equation Ax=B. If over- or underdetermined, it returns the least squares solution.

In MATLAB you compute this solution with

```matlab
x = A\B;
```

See [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html).

To explicitly use a least squares solver, use [`lsqr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqr.html), this is typically useful only for sparse matrices:

```matlab
x = lsqr(A, B);
```